# Android, Xamarin: Show 3 pictures from list in a row, then open up new row underneath

Tags: android, xamarin

My problem:
I made a recycleviewer that gets a list with images i download from a server before.

This list contains 6 pictures. 
I am trying to make the recviewer show 3 pictures in a row next to one another and then for the 4th picture open up a new row - containing the remainig three pics.

But for some reason I have not been able to find out yet, my inflater inflates SIX ROWS! First row shows the first element 3 times, second row the second pic 3 times in a row, 3rd the 3rd element three times, 4th the fourth and so on.

I found out with break points that my code does this line here 6 times:

```
                  LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context);
                  View itemView = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.RecView_Profile_Rows, parent, false);
                  return new RecyclerViewHolderRows(itemView, ctx);
```

This causes 6 rows to be filled. 
For a static test I did that to fill the imageviews:

```
RecyclerViewHolderRows viewHolder = holder as RecyclerViewHolderRows;
                    if (testcount == 1 || testcount == 4)
                    {
                        viewHolder.rowpic1.SetImageBitmap((lstData[position - 1].img));
                    }
                    else if (testcount == 2 || testcount == 5)
                    {
                        viewHolder.rowpic2.SetImageBitmap((lstData[position - 1].img));
                    }
                    else if(testcount == 3 || testcount == 6)
                    {
                        viewHolder.rowpic3.SetImageBitmap((lstData[position - 1].img));
                    }

                    testcount++;

                    viewHolder.SetItemClickListener(this);
```

That resulted in a wired pattern. Basically, in row 1 only the first of the thre pictures from left to right was filled - in row 2 it was the 2nd pic in row 3 the third. It then kept repeating once.

So, the problem is, that for some reason my layout gets inflated 6 times and I couldnt find a way to bypass that. Also, the only time I am using a loop is when I am filling up my list with data:

```
            lstData.Add(new DataForProfile()
            {
                imageId = startNumberOfTask,
                img = (Bitmap.CreateScaledBitmap
                (KumulosGeneral.DecodePhotoFromBase64(picture.photo),
                metrics.WidthPixels, metrics.WidthPixels, true)),
                description = picture.taskId.ToString()
            });
```

This leads me to question nr. 1: Where the hell comes the loop from that does 6 different inflats of my layout?

Question nr 2: How do I achieve the result I am looking for?

This is my layout for the rows:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img1_rec_profile_rows"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img2_rec_profile_rows"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img3_rec_profile_rows"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Can anybody help me out?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Where the hell comes the loop from that does 6 different inflates of my layout?

I guess your `lstData` must execute `Add` method 6 times, so `ItemCount` will return 6, and your `OnCreateViewHolder` will be called 6 times. All of these are normal.

> How do I achieve the result I am looking for?

1) Change your `DataForProfile` class, it should have three pictures properties 
 like img1, img2, img3, not only one `img`.

2) Change your `OnBindViewHolder` method, you can set picture for the three `ImageView` directly not `if-else`, like this:

```
viewHolder.rowpic1.SetImageBitmap((lstData[position - 1].img1));
viewHolder.rowpic2.SetImageBitmap((lstData[position - 1].img2));
viewHolder.rowpic3.SetImageBitmap((lstData[position - 1].img3));
```

---

At last, [Here is about `OnBindViewHolder` method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#onBindViewHolder(VH,%20int)), you can take a look.

Comment: okay great, thanks. but there is still an issue: in my add() method, I can now add the content to another imageview, but that tripples the results as the layout still is inmflated 6 times

Comment: No another `ImageView`, it is the `DataForProfile` has three pictures, img1, img2, img3 which you should add content to all of them in your `Add` method. So you just need execute `Add` method 2 times. And then the `lstData` should have two object. There should be three pictures responds to three `ImageView` in your layout.

Comment: okay thank you I get that, but I am really not sure how this add function works, would you help me out one last time? :)

Comment: this just lead to a problem: the onclick listener wont work anymore xD fml

Comment: It not about `Add` method, you need understand the usage of `ListView`, it is Adapter pattern, and the `DataForProfile` class (or other class in other `ListView`) should respond to the `ListView`'s item layout, like your three `ImageView`.  img1  responds to img1_rec_profile_rows, img2  responds to  img2_rec_profile_rows, img3 responds to img3_rec_profile_rows.

Comment: I suggest open a new case to ask `onclick listener wont work`.  BTW, you need use `SetOnClickListener` instead of  `SetItemClickListener`.

Comment: you helped me out great!